# react router redux url

Tags: reactjs, redux, browser-history, react-router-v4

I am making my first web-app using react, react router v4, and redux/react-router-redux.

it is a shopping site. I have my list of my products saved in the store and can access them fine. I have produced a products list page, when clicking on the products' image i have routing setup to take me to a new url(/'productmodel').

Currently I have a 'ProductPage' component for which I have passed in props relevant to the specific product, for each corresponding route, within my router. This seems like a very long way of doing things.

What I would like to do is render  for each of the routes and then have the ProductPage component itself, render the right product depending on the route (URL address).

What is the best way to do this??

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: God bless you using these libraries. Please consider if you really need `redux` together with `react-router`. In a SPA, sometimes only `react-router` is enough. Just consider using `redux` once you really need it, not because someone tells you that it's good.

Comment: Hi haotang, thanks for the encouragement. I have used redux because within my products list page I have filters which allow me to filter by brand, price range, etc. redux seemed like the best thing for doing so and it does seem like a great way now that I have it utilised.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this?

ProductsListPage:

```
....

render() {
   <div>
       {this.props.products.map(product => 
           <Link key={product.id} to={"/product/"+product.id}>
               {product.name}
           </Link>
       )}
   </div> 
}

....
```

ProductPage:

```
....

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.actions.getProduct(this.props.match.params.productid);
}

....

render() {
   <div>
       <span>{this.props.product.name}</Link>
   </div> 
}
....
```

Your route for product page would look like this:

```
<Route exact path="product/:productid" component={ProductPage} />
```

So what's happening here is when you click on a product on Products List page, you get redirected to the product page that has the product id as a parameter. On component mount on product page, you retrieve the product passing the productid from params (url).

Comment: Wow thanks Hossein, this seems like a great way to do it. and doesn't require me to connect my history to my redux store. I am going to give it a go and get back to this post once i'm done!

Comment: ok so this does not work out so easily for me. I am unable to use a getProduct function. what i want to do is retrieve the product which relates to the route path, from my product reducer (list of products) I then want to render only this product. I see that I can access the params from within my component, I am still struggling with how to tell my component to only use the product which matches the params. would using a connectedRouter, and a routerReducer  not help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I manage to do it!

I created a ProductPageContainer inorder to pass my products list from the store:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    let products = state.kitsProducts;
    return {
    products: products
    };
};
```

I then, within my component, got the productid from the params; as suggested by Hossein:

```
createProductPageComponent() {
    let activeProduct = this.props.products.filter(product => product.id === this.props.match.params.productid)
    return activeProduct.map(product =>{
        return (
            <ProductPage
                key={product.id}
                brand={product.brand}
                productName={product.model.toUpperCase()}
                price={"£"+product.price}
                productImage={product.image}
                text={product.text}
            />
        )
    })
}
```

and now my product page renders to the the right route, depending on which product was selected in the previous product list page. And the right product, depending on what route it has been rendered in.

Thanks Hossein!!! You helped me more than you may think!